# how to receive FCM push Notification even the app process was killed

Tags: java, android, push-notification, background-process

how to receive FCM push Notification even the app process is killed(application forced close)?
like receiving a notification on WhatsApp while the process not running!

Comment: You can use a service but it will drain battery faster and Service is also unreliable. And the second and the best way is to use Cloud Function to trigger the notifications.

Comment: @greywolf82 its forced process killed like cleaning apps 
the app will no longer be running in the background